# GitHub Project Pages: auto-redirect from sub-directory to sub-domain

Tags: javascript, redirect, github-pages

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097397/github-pages-setting-up-custom-domain) about a month ago regarding custom domains with Github Pages. I've since gotten everything set up and working correctly for both user/organization pages, as well as project pages.

My question this time is this: now that I have project page correctly set up to be available at both `www.domain.com/project/` and `project.domain.com` is there a way to redirect users who may visit "sub-directory" to the more desirable "sub-domain" URL?

I spoke with GitHub support and they said that I could accomplish this redirect with javascript, but didn't offer any further information. They obviously don't allow `.htaccess` files or any other type of server-side redirects. Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:** I'm aware that this should be done with `window.location.replace();` so what I really need to know is where in the repo this snippet should go.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to redirect users who go to `www.domain.com/project/` to `project.domain.com`?

Comment: You are correct, sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking to redirect the user from `www.domain.com/project/` to `project.domain.com` via JavaScript, you can add the following snippet to whatever resource exists at the URL:

```
var location = window.location;
if (
       location.hostname == "www.domain.com"
    && location.pathname.indexOf("/project") == 0
) {
    location.replace("http://project.domain.com");
}
```

(This is assuming that the resource at `www.domain.com/project/` is an HTML page that can have JavaScript.) You'll want to add this as close to the top of the page as possible to reduce the amount of time before the redirect (when it does happen).

As an aside: I would recommend *not* redirecting the user and using [canonical URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) to inform web crawlers what URL you like best. That is, adding the following to your `<head>`:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://project.domain.com">
```

Redirecting the user, especially after the whole page has loaded and JS has had time to execute is quite a poor user experience.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning canonical URLs, and for pointing out the performance hit. I'll take a look into this and report back.

Comment: So what this would do is allow users to still hit the `www.domain.com/project/` URL, but tell crawlers that the `project.domain.com` URL is preferred, correct?

Answer (score 1):

While you could do this with JavaScript, it may be better to use [META tags for SEO purposes](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html). You would add these tags to the head section of your `www.domain.com/project/` page:

```
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://project.domain.com"/>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://project.domain.com" />
```

These tags will specify a canonical page (helps prevent "Duplicate Content" SEO penalties from Google), and initiate a redirect via [page refresh](http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-meta-refresh.phtml) with delay of 0 seconds.

Here's a [sample page](https://github.com/ainc/AwesomeIncU/blob/master/_site/register2/index.html) (generated by [Jekyll Alias Generator plugin](https://github.com/tsmango/jekyll_alias_generator/blob/master/_plugins/alias_generator.rb)) that uses this technique to redirect visitors who land on [`/register2`](http://www.awesomeincu.com/register2) to the intended destination, [`/register`](http://www.awesomeincu.com/register)

Comment: Thanks for providing some great examples! Since the project "sub-directory" is a generated URL and not an actual folder in my repo, do I need to add one manually and put the above snippet inside of it?

Comment: Hmm...this could be tricky because it sounds like the 2 URLs (`www.domain.com/project/` and `project.domain.com`) are actually serving the same HTML file? If it's much less likely that a visitor would arrive on your `/project/` page, I'd recommend that you heed @Whymarrh's advice and simply use the canonical meta tag without a redirect.

Comment: Correct. By default GitHub serves project pages at `www.domain.com/project/`, but you can add set a CNAME record with DNS so that the project is also at `project.domain.com`. I doubt users will ever hit `/project/`, but it just seems weird to not be able to control that. Thanks @nicksuch!